# two times to exchange, find the minimum diff

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

There are two arrays `a[], b[];` `sum_a` is the sum of `a[]`, `sum_b` is the sum of `b[]` and `diff = |sum_a - sum_b|;`

now we have chance to exchange `a[i]` with `b[j]` for two times;

we want to get the minimum diff?

> example:
>   a = 7 7 5 5
>   b = 3 3 6 6

we can exchange 7 with 3, and exchange 5 with 6:

> a = 3 7 6 5
>   b = 7 3 5 6

so we can get the minimum diff is `(3+7+6+5)-(7+3+5+6) = 0;`

The question: how can program to find the minimum diff from the given arrays `a[] and b[]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using brute force algorithm. Below I used two loops to simulate one exchange, you can extend to simulate two exchanges. Demo in cpp.

```
int main()
 {
  int a[100];
  int b[100];
  int sumA=0;
  int sumB=0;
  int diff=0;

  int n;
  cin>>n;
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    cin>>a[i];
    sumA+=a[i];
  }
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    cin>>b[i];
    sumB+=b[i];
  }
  diff= abs(sumA-sumB);
  cout<<" Orig diff: " <<diff<<endl;
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n;j++){
          int tmp = abs(a[i]-b[j]);
          int newSumA = sumA+tmp;
          int newSumB = sumB-tmp;
          int newDiff = abs(newSumA-newSumB);
          if(newDiff<diff){
            diff = newDiff;
          }
        }
  }
  cout<<"Answer: "<<diff<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```